# How to set absolute position on elements in my case?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a container div that cover the screen with set `ratio`.

I want to place some elements with `absolute` position and to be responsive (scale down or up).

I have something like

http://jsfiddle.net/hsD2G/2/

When I shrink `width` or `height` of the browser. The element location will change and looks off. Can anyone help me about it?

Comment: Do you mean the `HIGHLIGHTS` image?

Comment: The problem is that the div is width:100%, so you can align the Highlights image to the BLOCK. But the bg image is specially positioned with `background-size: contain`, i.e. doesn't cover the entire block. It's not an element, so you can't achieve what you want. Try something different, like using a centered block, or calculating proportions with Javascript

Comment: @Hashem yes I mean highlight image.

Comment: @JavRok could you please show a simple example of how to do it in js? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Again, this is probably not the optimal solution. At least CSS can be used partly, to center the highlights image, or using %width. If you could, somehow, make the background image containing DIV to be squared, you could do it only with CSS. 
Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x8PJ/) with the jquery solution.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function update(){
        var top=20,left=40;
        var height = $(window).height();
        var width = $(window).width();
        var highlights = $('#cover-img img');
        if (height > width){
            // Image limited by width
            var blank_top = Math.round((height - width)/2);        
            highlights.css('top',blank_top+top);
            highlights.css('left',left);
            // make it responsive 1/3 ratio 
            highlights.width(Math.round(width/3));      
        }else{
            // Image limited by height
            var blank_left = Math.round((width - height)/2);        
            highlights.css('left',blank_left+left);
            highlights.css('top',top);        
            highlights.width(Math.round(height/3));
        }
    }
    $( window ).resize(update);

    update();
)};
```

Hope this helps